# Hostapd shows wlan0: AP-ENABLED, But SSID not Visible in Devices

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, hostapd

I am running `hostapd` on android devices on `adb shell` with following command.

```
hostapd -B /data/misc/wifi/hostapd.conf
```

it gives me following log

```
04-04 12:33:23.276  3052  3052 E hostapd : Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 00:0a:f5:33:62:98 and ssid "SSID"
04-04 12:33:23.385   712   712 I cnss-daemon: RTM_NEWROUTE Indication
04-04 12:33:23.387   800  3045 I LOWI-8.2.0.2.b: [LOWI-Scan] get_intf_mode: WLAN interface type 3, err 0
04-04 12:33:23.398  3052  3052 I hostapd : wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
04-04 12:33:23.398  3052  3052 I hostapd : wlan0: AP-ENABLED
04-04 15:36:35.520  3046  3046 D hostapd : wlan0: Setup of interface done.
04-04 15:36:35.520  3046  3046 D hostapd : ctrl_iface not configured!
```

I assume, `hostapd` is running properly. But I am not able to see the `SSID` in any Station or Device.

Also one more thing, `ignore_broadcast_ssid` is set to 0 in `hostapd.conf` which showcases that SSID is not hidden

I also knew that, Some `DNSMASQ` related configuration needs to be done. But I think `SSID` be visible on any Station or Device before that configuration.

Can anyone point me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever solve this one? I am having the same issue.

Comment: same thing for me

Comment: same here.. how did u fix that? @mf_starboi_8041

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem with Raspberry Pi 3. The problem was collision of wpa_supplicant with hostapd on Stretch. Solved by disabling wpa_supplicant with hostapd. Citing [Roger James](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/):

```
adding the following line to to the relevant WLAN interface stanzas in /etc/dhcpcd.conf.

nohook wpa_supplicant

e.g.

interface wlan0
nohook wpa_supplicant
static ip_address=192.168.0.1/24
```

Comment: I had to follow it up with a `sudo reboot` command but then everything worked out proper.